# Issue compiling Dockerfile on MacOS(apple Sillicon)

Tags: docker, macos, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, apple-m1

This is my first time to use Docker
I build a Dockerfile and use the Vscode remote container to open folder in Container.
When I run this Dockerfile on Windows 11. It does not have any problem
But When I run it on MacOS(apple Sillicon). It have error.
after I step by step to check the Dockerfile.
I find that if I install g++multilib or libc6-dev-i386, it will get error.
I do not have any idea about why?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update \
&& apt-get -y install gcc g++ python \
&& apt-get -y install python-dev \
&& apt-get -y install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev \
&& apt-get -y install  mercurial \
&& apt-get -y install  bzr \
&& apt-get -y install cmake libc6-dev \
&& apt-get -y install  gdb valgrind \
&& apt-get -y install  flex bison libfl-dev \
&& apt-get -y install  tcpdump \
&& apt-get -y install  sqlite sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev \
&& apt-get -y install  gsl-bin libgslcblas0 \
&& apt-get -y install  libxml2 libxml2-dev \
&& apt-get -y install  libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-dev \
&& apt-get -y install  vtun lxc \
&& apt -y install git \
&& apt -y install npm \
&& apt-get -y install g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386
```

devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "802.11ah ns-3 simulation",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "appPort": 3000,
    "extensions": ["dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"],
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    }
}
```

error information: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE04I.jpg

Comment: Can you reconfigure your build system to produce text-format errors, and replace the image link with the actual text of the error?  What are you building that you need three different source-control systems, two language interpreters plus an extended C build toolchain, and network-debugging tools; can you reduce the Dockerfile to a [mcve] (what is the smallest Dockerfile that produces the same error)?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have specified the architetture of Ubuntu container in docker file. Apple silicon have ARM architecture, not all image are compatibile.